# How to create a real bandpass filter?

Tags: filters, python, bandpass

I'm trying to create a real bandpass filter (17-point) in Python by calculating the coefficients b of a signal. This is the formula I'm using:
$$b = \cos(ω(k-k_m))$$
for $k = 0,1,..,L-1$, where $k_m$ is the midpoint of the impulse response,
$$k_m = 1/2(L-1)$$
I calculated omega with this formula:
$$ω = 2πf/f_s$$
where $f_s=16000$ Hz and $f= 960$ Hz and therefore $ω = 0.12π$. The bandpass should be a 17 point bandpass filter. I suppose thats the $L$ in the formula if I'm correct, and therefore
$$k_m = 1/2(L-1) = 1/2(17-1) = 8$$
So when putting all calculated variables in the formula i get:
$$b = \cos(0.12π(k-8))$$
where $k$ is $0,1,...,16$. When calculating the coefficients for every $k$ until $16$ i get this coefficients array, which I use to filter my signal:

```
coefficients = np.array((-0.9921147013144778, -0.8763066800438634,-0.6374239897486894,-0.30901699437494734,0.06279051952931353,0.4257792915650728, 0.7289686274214116, 0.9297764858882515, 1.0, 0.9297764858882515, 0.7289686274214116,  0.4257792915650728,  0.06279051952931353,-0.30901699437494734,-0.6374239897486894, -0.8763066800438634, -0.9921147013144778))
```

However, this real bandpass should also have the center frequency 2000 Hz. My questions is how do I implement the center frequency, because I already have the coefficients(if I did it right) and if there is an easier way to calculate all this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest ways to generate a bandpass FIR filter in Python are to use one of `firwin` or `remez`.

Below are four filters: your original (blue), another like your original that is centered on 2000 Hz (green), a `remez` design (orange), and an `firwin` design (red).

The impulse responses are:

[image: Impulse responses]

The frequency responses are:

[image: Frequency responses]

Depending on your requirements, either the orange (`remez`) or red (`firwin`) designs are closer to what you want.

---

## Python code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import remez, freqz, firwin

L = 17
k = np.arange(L)
km = (L-1)/2
fs = 16000
f = 960
f_center = 2000
omega = 2*f/fs*np.pi
omega_center = 2*f_center/fs*np.pi

b = np.cos(omega*(k-km))
b2 = np.cos(omega_center*(k-km))
           

edges = [0, f_center-f/2-160, f_center-f/2+160, f_center+f/2-160, f_center+f/2+160, fs/2 ]
b1 = remez(L, edges, [0, 1, 0], Hz=fs)
b3 = firwin(L, [f_center-f/2, f_center+f/2], pass_zero=False, fs=fs)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(b)
plt.plot(b1)
plt.plot(b2)
plt.plot(b3)

plt.figure(2)
w, mag = freqz(b, fs=fs)
w, mag1 = freqz(b1, fs=fs)
w, mag2 = freqz(b2, fs=fs)
w, mag3 = freqz(b3, fs=fs)
plt.plot(w,np.abs(mag)/np.abs(mag).max())
plt.plot(w, np.abs(mag1)/np.abs(mag1).max())
plt.plot(w, np.abs(mag2)/np.abs(mag2).max())
plt.plot(w, np.abs(mag3)/np.abs(mag3).max())
```